# Why is gulp not available in Laravel 6 for production version?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, deployment, production

I recently developed Laravel application with React Front end! I need to know how can I create production version of this project!

in the package.json file i see there is option for  `npm run production` but I dont see any option for composer production build or anything for Laravel. Can someone guide me please. I have read the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment)  it doesn't mention gulp or any other command.

My Package.json File

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "react": "^16.8.0-alpha.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0-alpha.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.31",
    "formik": "^2.0.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
}
```

}

Comment: Post the package.json file please.

Comment: I edited the question, you can see the package.json file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gulp is not anymore recommended.
But still, you can find some documentation on Laravel v5.3 : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

See on Github the version at the time (`package.json` and `gulpfile.js`) : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3

Comment: whats new in place of gulp?

Comment: @AliWaqas I have updated my answer with links. Also gulp has been replaced by webpack. See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json and https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js

Comment: Thank you. so npm run production is the replacement for gulp .